# How to access camera in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How to access camera in nativescript without opening camera activity?

I used following code but it is opening device camera application. And I am expecting it should take picture without opening camera, or add camera view in application itself like whatsapp web scan.

```
import cameraModule = require("camera");
import imageModule = require("ui/image");
cameraModule.takePicture().then(picture => {
    console.log("Result is an image source instance");
    var image = new imageModule.Image();
    image.imageSource = picture;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The "[camera](https://docs.nativescript.org/hardware/camera)" module of NativeScript is an abstraction for the OS specific camera module which is why it opens that native interface.

In order to open a custom "nested" camera view a custom implementation would be required. Here comes the power of NativeScript and more specifically its plugin extensibility. You can either [write such plugin](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins) yourself or looks for an existing one. As the idea of "nested" camera UI is very specific and would probably rely on app specific styles I was not able to find such existing plugin. [Here](https://www.airpair.com/android/android-camera-surface-view-fragment) for example you can see how something like this would be implemented in native Android, the same is probably possible in iOS also.